# Error in qiskit.aqua.operator

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, qiskit, programming

I want to implement this thing: 
`Operator([[3, Pauli([1,0,0], [0,0,0])], [2, Pauli([0,0,0],[0,0,3])]])`

But while doing this there is an error in `"qiskit.aqua.operator"` 
How can we fix this?

The main problem is to run this notebook completely without any error:
https://gitlab.com/qosf/qml-mooc/-/blob/master/qiskit_version/07_Variational_Circuits.ipynb

If anybody had able to complete this notebook then my all doubts would be cleared.

Comment: Hi! What Qiskit version are you using and what is the full error?